# React Frontend not sending messages to Node.js Backend

Tags: javascript, express, fetch-api, nodemailer

I'm making an email contact form for a website and the handleSubmit function is timing out before it can connect to the node.js backend, even though the server is running. I need help getting the frontend to send data to the backend. Even though I know for sure the server runs, as when I mistakenly ran both the server and website on port 3000 the code sent undefined emails to the server (at the cost of the website ceasing to work when reloaded), the code now keeps sending 404 errors in the website console. Thank you very much!
(I've tried Fetch and Axios both, and neither work. The fetch code is more reliable though).

Here is the function:

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  const formInfo = new FormData(form);
  const jsonBody = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formInfo));
  console.log(jsonBody);
  async function fetchData() {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3002/send", {
      method: "POST",
      body: jsonBody,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === "fail") {
          alert("Message failed to send.");
        }
      });
  }
  fetchData();
}
```

Even async/await isn't helping. This was the original version:

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  const formInfo = new FormData(form);
  const jsonBody = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formInfo));
  console.log(jsonBody);
  fetch("http://localhost:3002/send", {
    method: "POST",
    body: jsonBody,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === "success") {
        alert("Message Sent.");
        this.resetForm();
      } else if (response.status === "fail") {
        alert("Message failed to send.");
      }
    });
}
```

This backend code was copied from a tutorial with changes:

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var cors = require("cors");
const creds = require("./config");

// email details here

router.post("/send", (req, res, next) => {
  var content = req.body;
  var mail = {
    from: " ",
    to: "earnzek@gmail.com",
    subject: "New Message from Contact Form",
    text: content,
  };
  transport.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        status: "fail",
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        status: "success",
      });
    }
  });
});
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {});
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(3002);
```

Comment: This is a version without it, but those weren't helping either. When inspected, the network tab showed that the codes are 200, but the "server request time" is too long.

Comment: I edited it, and the same "message failed to send" alert pops up.

Comment: Currently it looks to be the same thing happening as when the 200 codes popped up but the message still failed to send. My network tab when inspected is no longer showing that data for some reason, but the server is still running.

Comment: So now it's _"Message failed to send"_ which means your `transport.sendMail()` resulted in an error. Instead of completely ignoring that `err`, you should at least log it so you know what went wrong... `if (err) { console.error('sendMail failed', err); res.status(500).json({ status: 'fail' }); }`. Then check your terminal where you're running the server

Comment: `transport` is undeclared.

Comment: FYI `req.body` is an **object** which does not fit the [Nodemailer message definition](https://nodemailer.com/message/) for `text`... _"The plaintext version of the message as an Unicode string, Buffer, Stream or an attachment-like object (`{path: ‘/var/data/…'}`)"_

Comment: @Odri presumably hidden behind the _"email details here"_ comment. The error would be completely different if that was the problem

Comment: The argument must be of type string, apparently. I thought it was stringified.

Comment: Thank you very much Phil! I got the error you just commented as the FYI. How do I make it into text?

Comment: Which properties from the request JSON do you want as the text? You didn't include the details of your `<form>` so nobody can tell. If you have an `<input>` named `content` for example, you would use `req.body.content`

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I didn't know you could .(key) JSON files like that. I will try that.  Thank you very, very much, truly.

Comment: JSON is just the serialisation format you're using for the request body. The `express.json()` middleware parses the request body into a plain object. There are no _"JSON files"_ involved at all. The lesson I hope you take from this is **never ignore errors**, especially ones you **catch**.